# wordpress simple paypal shopping cart shortcode in custom fields

Tags: wordpress

i”m using wordpress simple paypal shopping cart and i want to parse the shortcode into custom field, i”ve found an example but it”s not working

above the loop i”ve put this
`<?php $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, ‘price’, true ); ?>`

and where i want to display the add to cart button i have this 
`<?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($name, $price); ?>`

it”s not working right

the add to cart button apear on every post, when u press it it add product in cart with no name and no price
when i add key=price and value= 25 it add to cart same noname and noprice product :(

btw the shortcode i want to parse it”s looks like this [wp_cart:PRODUCT NAME:price:PRODUCT PRICE:end]

Answer (score 0):

this is how u do it
 `<?php $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price', true ); ?>

            <?php $name = get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product($name, $price); ?>`

that code display the add to cart button

```
Price: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price', true); ?> $
```

and that”s for the price to be displayed

have fun

Answer (score 0):

To keep things organize the code it will look like this

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'PRODUCT-PRICE', true ); ?>
  Price: $<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PRODUCT-PRICE', true); ?> 
  Product Name: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'PRODUCT-NAME', true); ?>
<?php $name = get_the_title(); ?> <?php echo print_wp_cart_button_for_product
($name, $price); ?>
```